# Submit button takes 2 clicks to generate output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, form-submit

I am trying to update state in react only after form is submitted. I have one html form which has 1 text input and a submit button, but it takes 2 click of submit button to actually change the state in react. I am using 2 methods `handleSubmit` and `handleChange`.

`handleChange` look for changes in input field and update the state accordingly.

`handleSubmit` append the state updated by `handleChange` to array on form submission

and state contains { itemslist: [], currentitem: "" }

when 1st time submit button is clicked it gives previous value of item (or gives empty array) and at 2nd time it gives array with value present in input field.

below is my full code

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentitem: '',
      itemslist: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return{
        itemslist: prevState.itemslist.concat([this.state.currentitem])
      }
    })

    console.log(this.state.items)
  }

  handleChange(event){
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({ [name] : value })
    console.log(this.state.currentitem)
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <input type='text' placeholder='enter text' name='currentitem' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.currentitem} />
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: State setting in React is asynchronous, so you can't `console.log` it on the next line and expect it to be updated

Comment: @Jayce444 is right, if you wanna check the value of currentItem then you should log it in your render method, that way you can see its updated on each render.

Comment: @JoeLloyd Thank You, it is showing output in render method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer could be a bit different of your code but this way it will work. Set the button type to button and make the button handle the submit, not the form. Then change the handleSubmit function to what I've got. I've tried it and it does works!:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentitem: '',
      itemslist: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const { currentitem, itemslist } = this.state;
    const newArray = [
      ...itemslist,
      currentitem
    ];
    this.setState({ itemslist, newArray });
  }

  handleChange(event){
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({ [name] : value })
    console.log(this.state.currentitem)
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type='text' placeholder='enter text' name='currentitem' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.currentitem} />
          <button type='button' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>

        // In cas eyou want to see the values in the array+
        {
            this.state.itemsList.map((item) => <p>{item}</>)
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

**setState** function is **asynchronous** in react, so you cannot get the updated value immediately. But if you need to get the recent updated value from state, you must use **callback** function of **setState**.

```
this.setState({items: newItems}, () => { console.log(); })
```

I have modified your example like below to fulfil your requirement.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentitem: '',
            items: []
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                items: prevState.items.concat([this.state.currentitem])
            }
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.items)
        });
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        this.setState({[name]: value});
        console.log(this.state.currentitem);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='enter text' name='currentitem' onChange={this.handleChange}
                           value={this.state.currentitem}/>
                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```